# javascript parameters for callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have function which is call recursively by ajax complete callback, and I need to set parameters fot this function. But how do I transfer parameters in callback?

```
function poll(url, data, pollDelay, type){
            $.ajax({ url: url, type: 'POST', data: data, success: function(data){
                if(data != '' && type == 1) { //do answers
                doOutput(data);
                }
            }, dataType: 'html', complete: pollTimeout = setTimeout('poll()', pollDelay), timeout: 30000 });
    }

function doPoll() {
    clearTimeout(pollTimeout);
    poll('url/f.php', obj = { id: someId, data: somedata }, 10000, 1);
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to your `setTimeout` call? Never pass a string to `setTimeout`.

```
pollTimeout = setTimeout(function() {poll(url,data,pollDelay,type);},pollDelay);
```

Note that your whole "complete" thing should be in such a function:

```
$.ajax({...
    complete: function() {
        pollTimeout = setTimeout(...);
    }
...});
```